# Run a class in cmd through java code

Tags: java, cmd

Hi guys :) I'm actually working on a project and i have to execute a class in a new command prompt, but i have to do it using java. So in a specific class Class, i have to write the right code which call the class Sensor in a new command prompt.
i have this code lines which opens a new command prompt but how to make it execute the class Sensor on that command prompt opened ?

```
 String[] command =(new String[]{"cmd", "/k", "start", "cmd" , "\""});
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Any help would be appreciated!! 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please show us your Sensor class?

Comment: @timothyclifford It's a bit complicate but something like :  (It's not complete)  public class Sensor{ public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        do { // MAKES A REST POST REQUEST TO A SERVER REST                                            // RECEIVES THE RESPONSE  Sensor.simulation(type, idnumber); // ACTIVATE THE SENSOR        sensors.Sensor.tokenManagement(prevPort,nextId,nextPort);// MANAGE THE TOKEN} System.out.println("Push exit to delete the sensor");{
            //DELETE REQUEST TO SERVER REST }//RESPONSE FROM SERVER, {System.exit(1);}

Comment: Please take a look on [Output from command prompt returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113931/) to understand what `cmd /c start cmd.exe /K` or other variants like above `cmd /k start cmd` mean which looks like many Java programmers use without knowing what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
it will open cmd and execute the command passed to it
To Compile the java file.

```
String command="cmd /c \""+drive+" && cd "+fileParentDrive+" && javac "+javaFileName+"\"";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

To run class file

```
command="cmd.exe /k start cmd.exe /k \""+drive+" && java "+classFileName+"\"";
child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command , null , new File(drive+ parent));
```

Method `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` will return the reference of `Process` Class. now you can get the output of the file while executing on cmd as follow

To get errors if occurs at compile time

```
InputStream in = child.getErrorStream();
int i;
String error="";
while((i=in.read())!=-1)
{
    error+=(char)i;
}
```